# Does [CORMEN90] demonstrate prior art for this order statistic tree patent?

Tags: prior-art-request, us6735595

In reference to the patent: [US6735595](https://www.google.com/patents/US6735595)

This patent appears to describe various implementations of what is usually known in the computer science community as an [order statistic tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Order_statistic_tree&oldid=640671014).  In particular, the two pseudocode algorithms in the patent document - "ORDINAL" and "FINDKEY" - are fairly straightforward adaptations of "OS-RANK" and "OS-SELECT" from [3] (section 14.1).  Many papers from before the issue of this patent (for instance, [5], [6] and [7]) reference the first edition of that text [4], published in 1990, when describing their use of order-statistic trees.

From reading the patent, I can find nothing within the claims that goes significantly beyond a normal understanding of order-statistic trees, such as may be obtained by reading [4].  The patent's descriptions are couched mainly in the language of B-trees and digital (i.e. prefix) trees, rather than the binary trees described in [4], but it is clear that the core idea (and supposed innovation) - that of storing an item count at the head of every subtree and using it to rank/unrank keys - is invariant to the type of tree.  Am I right in thinking that this constitutes prior art for this patent?

[3]: Cormen, Thomas H.; Leiserson, Charles E., Rivest, Ronald L., Stein, Clifford (2001) [1990]. Introduction to Algorithms (2nd ed.). MIT Press and McGraw-Hill. ISBN 0-262-03293-7.

[4]:  Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, and Ronald L. Rivest. Introduction to Algorithms. MIT Electrical Engineering and Computer Science Series. MIT Press and McGraw-Hill, Cambridge, Massachusetts and New York, New York, 1990.

[5]: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~ava/NORSIG96.pdf - Valmari, Antti. "Optimality results for median computation." Proceedings of Nordic Signal Processing Symposium. 1996.

[6]: http://www.cs.umn.edu/tech_reports_upload/1993/HidingJitter.pdf - Frankowski, Daniel, and John Riedl. Hiding jitter in an audio stream. Technical Report No. TR-93-50, Department of Computer Science, University of Minnesota, 1993.

[7]: http://www.textfiles.com/bitsavers/pdf/mit/lcs/tr/MIT-LCS-TR-638.pdf - Ernst, Michael D. Serializing parallel programs by removing redundant computation. MS thesis. Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Dept. of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, 1992.